# Tensorflow graph running without providing placeholders

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have been struggling for hours trying to understand this [code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/udacity/6_lstm.ipynb) but I just can't.

In cell 9, line 13 it loops:

```
for i in range(num_unrollings + 1):       
    feed_dict[train_data[i]] = batches[i]
```

Which means that in the *first* execution only `train_data[0]` has a value. `train_data[1]` is still a placeholder.

When you look at the graph definition in cell 8, line 48:

```
train_labels = train_data[1:]
```

The graph requires `train_data[1]` to exist because if it doesn't you don't have any labels!

So my question is: how does this work? It doesn't crash, it works perfectly. Why doesn't the first execution raise an exception? How can the session be run with a placeholder still in place?

It should raise a

> InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder_1' with dtype float and shape [64,27]

exception shouldn't it?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, I was very specific in my question.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what's bothering you: num_unrollings is a constant (10), so the feed_dict is filled with train_data[0] through train_data[10]. This entire feed_dict is filled before the first call to session.run (which occurs on the next line, after the loop completes). Why wouldn't this work?

Comment: OMG, I'm a retard. Because there is a "_," before the line I wasn't looking at the indentation correctly. I was looking at it as if the session run was inside the loop. Thanks for bringing that to my attention.